# How to scrape data into an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/ag25.dat

I'm trying to scrape data from the UIUC airfoil database website but all of the links are formatted differently than the other. I tried using pandas read table and use `skiprows`
to skip the non-data point part of the url but every url have a different number of rows to skip.
How can I manage to only read the numbers in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_fwf()` which will read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame:

In terms of how to handle different files with different rows to skip, what we could do is once the file is read, just count the rows until there is a line that contains only numeric values. Then feed that into the `skiprows` parameter.

In the case of values greater than 1.0, we can simply just filter those out from the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import requests

url = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/ag25.dat'
response = requests.get(url).text

for idx, line in enumerate(response.split('\n'), start=1):
    if all([x.replace('.','').isdecimal() for x in line.split()]):
        break
    skip = idx    

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(response), skiprows=skip, header=None)
df = df[~(df > 1).any(1)]
```

**Output:**

```
    print(df)
                0         1
    0    1.000000  0.000283
    1    0.994054  0.001020
    2    0.982050  0.002599
    3    0.968503  0.004411
    4    0.954662  0.006281
    ..        ...       ...
    155  0.954562  0.001387
    156  0.968423  0.000836
    157  0.982034  0.000226
    158  0.994050 -0.000374
    159  1.000000 -0.000680
    
    [160 rows x 2 columns]

**Option 2:**

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/b707b.dat'
response = requests.get(url).text

lines = []
for idx, line in enumerate(response.split('\n'), start=1):
    if all([x.replace('.','').replace('-','').isdecimal() for x in line.split()]):
        lines.append(line)

lines = [x.split() for x in lines]
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df = df.astype(float)
df = df[~(df > 1).any(1)]
```

Comment: can you make a limitation? let us say only numeric values that are less than 10

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean? Whats an url where we'd see this?

Comment: so some of the url have a number on top. <https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/b707b.dat> For this url it would be 16.0. All of the data base points are below 1.0 and 1.0 is the max. Is there a way to make 1.0 as the limit so It doesn't pick up the 16.0?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for that. Yup, we can fix that.

Comment: Ok it's updated. Just that 1 extra line `df = df[~(df > 1).any(1)]`

Comment: <https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/e231.dat> the code doesn't work for this certain url. Can you be able to make it work for this url as well?

Comment: so is 1 and 0 for those not supoose to be part of the table, or should they be included

Comment: It is suppose to be included, I get an error message of `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`